# remove rows from pyspark dataframe by type

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, filter, pyspark

I have large file with product items in a pyspark, some of them are exact numbers and other contain strings.
I want to remove all row items with numbers from the dataframe (computationally efficient).

```
|Product-1| Pj3f|
|Product-2| 12  |
|Product-3| Pj2F|
|Product-4| 20  |
```

How do i filter rows by type of an item in a column of a pyspark dataframe? 
The pyspark filter function does not seem to have functionality for it.

k

Answer (score 2):

**`cast`** the column to **`int`** then filter only the **`null`** value columns.

- Or by using **`.rlike`** function

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---------+-----+
#|  product|descr|
#+---------+-----+
#|Product-1| pj3f|
#|product-2|   12|
#+---------+-----+

df.filter(col("descr").cast("int").isNull()).show()
df.filter(~col("descr").rlike("^([\s\d]+)$")).show()
#+---------+-----+
#|  product|descr|
#+---------+-----+
#|Product-1| pj3f|
#+---------+-----+
```

Comment: @anky, `rlike` match with regular expression, kind of `like` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.rlike

Answer (score 0):

Columns in spark are all of the same type. If you mix two columns with a `union` for example of different types, spark will try to transform to a valid type for both, usualy `String`, and puts the string representation of the values.

Examples:

- A `String` column and a `Float`, will result into a `String` column, with the floats represented in a string with the dot for decimals. `String + Float => String`
- A `Integer` column union a `Float` will transform all the integers into Floats. `Integer + Float => Float`

For your case will depend, if its a topical string or numeric, I would go for the [regex](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@regexp_extract(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exp:String,groupIdx:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) filtering.

```
val stringsDF = df.filter(regex_extract($"column", "[0-9]+([.|,][0-9]+)?") === ""))
```

This will keep all values that don't follow a float or integer value.